# Caracteres basuras aleatorios al final de un arreglo char en c++

Tags: c++, array

Estoy intentando extraer la primera palabra de un arreglo char (completa) e insertar esa palabra en otro arreglo (orden) del mismo tipo, para así luego compararla con otros dos arreglos (uno y dos) de tipo char que contienen la palabra "ascendiente" y "descendiente" como pueden ver en el código.

Mi código funciona bien pero me inserte una serie de caracteres basura al finalizar el arreglo y  estos caracteres aparecen de forma aleatoria, es decir que existe casos en donde no aparecen dichos caracteres y cuando aparecen no siempre son lo mismo y por lo tanto a la hora de comparar la cadena de orden con uno y dos, no lo hace de forma correcta y destruye el resto del código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        char completa[]="ascendente 3 5 2 10 40 50 60 70 80 90 10 100 11 45 45 45";
        char orden[12];
        char numeros[1000];
        char uno[]="ascendente";
        char dos[]="descendente";
        int i=0, j=0;


        while(completa[i]!=' ') //Se extrae la primera palabra del string y se define la variable orden que puede ser ascendente o descendente
            {
                orden[i]=completa[i];
                i++;
            }

        if(strcmp(orden,uno)==0){
            cout<<"entrando en ascendente"<<endl;
            for(i=11;i<strlen(completa);i++){
                numeros[j]=completa[i];
                j++;
                }
            }
            
        else if(strcmp(orden,dos)==0){
            cout<<"entrando en descendente"<<endl;
            for(i=12;i<strlen(completa);i++){
                numeros[j]=completa[i];
                j++;
                }
            }

        else{
            cout<<"NO VALIDO"<<endl;
            cout<<orden<<endl;
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta colocar en el *arreglo* `orden[]` el `0` que marque la final de los datos *mostrables*:

```
...
while(completa[i]!=' ')
{
    orden[i]=completa[i];
    i++;
}

orden[i] = 0;
...
```